# how to launch event on specific cell in datagradview

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

The `datagridview` has an event that will be lunched on `CellLeave` any cell within the `datagridview` what I really need is to lunch on `CellLeave` on specific cell

**Example**

I have `datagridview` with `column1`,`column2`,`column3`, and `column4` I want to do the following

1- enter id in `column1`

2- an event will be lunched exmple `CellLeave event`

3- The event will lookup for the rest of columns values within my database where the data entered in `column1` will be a primary key ...

4- if prirmay key found it will return the data to `datagridview` clolumns
else nothing will happen

so how i can lunch the event on specific cell in `datagridview` **NOT** on any cell ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have the event handled for only specific cells. What you will have to do is just have the CellLeave event for each cell and then in the event handler only do the processing for the cells you want.

```
void datagridview1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    //or however else you'll determine it's a cell that you want to process on
    if (e.RowIndex == 1) {
        //any processing you want to do
    }
}
```

I'm not certain what you're actually wanting to do, but from what you described it doesn't sound like you'll be wanting to use CellLeave anyways, perhaps CellEndEdit.